# ReactComponentTreeHook unexpected : Webpack 2

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I am trying to use React/Webpack2 and it's working in the dev mode. But when I tried to switch to the production mode I got an error about:

```
ReactComponentTreeHook.js:164 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I checked the source code and saw that stuff it looks like everything is fine, but it doesn't work somehow.

```
process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? warning(element, 'ReactComponentTreeHook: Missing React element for debugID %s when ' + 'building stack', id) : void 0;
```

Thanks for any help!

I am use a pretty standard config (from the webpack2 off docs)

.babelrc
    {
        "presets": [
            ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
            // webpack understands the native import syntax, and uses it for tree shaking

```
        "stage-2",
        // Specifies what level of language features to activate.
        // Stage 2 is "draft", 4 is finished, 0 is strawman.
        // See https://tc39.github.io/process-document/

        "react"
        // Transpile React components to JavaScript
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "react-hot-loader/babel"
        // Enables React code to work with HMR.
    ]
}
//
//{
//    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
//    "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
//}
```

webpack.common.config

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var precss = require('precss');

var webpack = require("webpack"),
    helpers = require("./helpers"),
    glob = require("glob"),

    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin"),

    srcName = "src";

module.exports = {
    entry : [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        // activate HMR for React

        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5000',
        // bundle the client for webpack-dev-server
        // and connect to the provided endpoint

        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        // bundle the client for hot reloading
        // only- means to only hot reload for successful updates

        'babel-polyfill',
        helpers.root(srcName, "index.js")
    ],
    context : helpers.root(srcName),
    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                enforce : 'pre',
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                loader : 'eslint-loader',
                options: {
                    fix: true,
                },
                include: helpers.root(srcName)
            },
            {
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders : [
                    'babel-loader',
                ],
                exclude : /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test : /\.css$/,
                loaders : [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?modules',
                    'postcss-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins : [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options : {
                // Javascript lint
                eslint : {
                    configFile : '.eslintrc',
                    failOnWarning : false,
                    failOnError : false
                }
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.prod.config

```
var helpers = require("./helpers"),
    commonConfig = require("./webpack.common.js"),
    webpack = require("webpack"),

    webpackMerge = require("webpack-merge"),

    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    CssSourcemapPlugin = require("css-sourcemaps-webpack-plugin"),
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin"),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");


const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = "production";

//   path : helpers.root("dist"),
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool : "source-map",

    output : {
        path : helpers.root("dist"),
        publicPath : "/",
        filename : "[name].[hash].js",
        chunkFilename : "[id].[hash].chunk.js"
    },

    plugins : [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            rootPath : "",
            template : "index.ejs"
        }),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            children : true,
            async : true,
        }),
        new CssSourcemapPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env" : {
                "ENV" : JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "giffy_search",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The Gif Search Engine",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "deploy": "rimraf ./dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/wellnine/giffySearch.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "search",
    "gif",
    "engine"
  ],
  "author": "Sviat Wellnine",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/wellnine/giffySearch/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/wellnine/giffySearch#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-native-modules": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "css-sourcemaps-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "ejs-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "eslint": "^3.12.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.8.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "stats-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.27",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was in the

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env" : {
        "ENV" : JSON.stringify(ENV)
    }
})
```

Changed it to:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
    }
}),
```

Now it's working :) Maybe it will save a lot of hours  for someone.